# How to make side navigation bar as same as of playstore

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to make side navigation bar as same as in playsotre with backpress enabled.
As in Goggle Play Store app, HomeFragment/Home screen is shown as we open the app but HomeFragment is not shown/mentioned in side navigation bar.
I want this thing in my app.

and also, if we move to My Apps then press back button after that we moved to HomeFragment.

[image]

This is HomeFragment/Home screen of Play Store. In red circle you can see Humburger icon for open side navigation bar.

[image]

In picture 2, we can see that their is no HomeFragment/Home screen shown or mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `Navigation View` lets take this example :
this is the main `xml` file (the layout you want to put the bar inside it) and it will be a `drawer layout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="start"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

a toolbar instead of action bar and the relative layout will just debug the bugs
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"
    android:background="#9C27B0"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
</RelativeLayout>

this is the navigation view
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_view_menu"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The `tools:openDrawer="start"` represents where the menu appears left or right,
the `nav header` is the picture at top of the `navigation_view`
, the `app:menu` is the `navigation_view` menu

---

This is the main activity :

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawerLayout drawerLayout ;
NavigationView navigationView ;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //this will make toolbar instead of action bar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar) ;
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout) ;

    navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view) ;

    // if user select item from the navigation view it will be detected here
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.item1 : System.out.println("item 1 selected") ; break;
                case R.id.item2 : System.out.println("item 2 selected") ; break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    // this is important part to add button in the toolbar
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,toolbar,R.string.open_nav,R.string.close_nav) ;

    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle) ;
}
}
```

---

And this is the `nav_header` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="170dp"
android:background="#4CAF50">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="this is nav header"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`layout_height` is preferred 170

---

And you must create a menu like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">

you create a group and dont't forget to set checkable beavior to single and then
add your items
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/item1" android:title="this is item1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/item2" android:title="this is item2"/>
</group>

</menu>
```

`tools:showIn="navigation_view` is very important !

---

Befor everything you must add `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'` in dependencies in your `build.gradle (moudle)` file

---

and add this at your `strings.xml` file :
`<string name="open_nav">navigation_view_opened</string>      <string name="close_nav">navigation_view_closed</string>`

---

To hide the `action bar` (very important) do this to your `styles.xml` :

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

_________________________________________________________________________________
The codes result :

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for you help but this is not my answer

Comment: @Buddy ok so,I want to help you,what exactly you want?

Comment: i have edited my question. brother you can check it

Comment: @Buddy I can help you better if you included a photo because , playstore has alot of bars

Comment: Brother now i have attached some pictures.

Comment: @Buddy This is very good news brother , because this is exactly my answer , and the "bar" actuly called `navigation view`

Comment: thanks brother i really appreciate your help.  If you are comfortable, can we connect on social media. I am available on Telegram and Instagram.

Comment: hey brother check my new problem.. please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64767123/store-offline-firebase-database-android    @a7d.24_